# readdir() in linux sometimes not returning correct string utf8

Tags: linux, utf-8, readdir

I have a file in a folder with name as

`01一千个伤心的理由 张学友`

but sometimes readdir() is simply returning all `?????????` as the name of the file.

I searched for this on google and found that readdir has some utf-8 issue on some systems (like [this one](http://comp.sys.mac.programmer.codewarrior.narkive.com/mkWSWblX/readdir-not-returning-correctly-encoded-unicode-characters)). Did I read correct? If on linux, this is the problem then is there any solution?

**EDIT** 
The problem is that there are actually two scripts (one is mine and there is another also) which are mounting the same device on two different paths. I am mounting as `utf-8` but the other one is not mounting it as `utf-8` (its probably in default mode). So if mine script runs first on reboot or device insert, everything is fine. Otherwise the problem comes.

So the question is why the two mounts are affecting the other one and how can I correct it?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you run readdir on the same directory multiple times and get different results for the same particular directory entry? That would be unusual. For the record, I have no trouble creating a file with the name you specified above, and readdir works reliably on it. (BTW I think that link [which was OSX-specific] concerned someone who was looking for a version of readdir that would auto-convert utf-8 to wchars. I don't see any indication that there was an issue with utf-8 per se.)

Answer (score 1):

On Linux (or more generally, POSIX), pathnames are just a bunch of arbitrary bytes terminated by a '\0' (ASCII NULL) character, with pathname components separated by '/'. Every other byte value is allowed. How to interpret those bytes is up to the application. So most likely your problem has to do with different locale settings etc. E.g. "script 1" creates a pathname which contains invalid UTF-8 but happens to be correctly printable characters in whatever locale that "script 1" is running in.